# BooleanGetMethodName warning in phpmd

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, jenkins, phpmd

I generate my entities using doctrine mapping in symfony2, and get this code:

```
/**
 * Get active
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function getActive() {
    return $this->active;
}
```

Using jenkins and PMD plugin, they throw BooleanGetMethodName warnings and suggest that because getActive function return boolean, it should be renamed to isActive or hasActive.

I have a lot of files that have this warning. Is it good to suppress the warnings? If yes, how? Or should I replace all functions name returning boolean value in symfony2 entity to follow jenkins and PMD rule?

Comment: Yes, every boolean value sould have an isValue or hasValue "getter"

Comment: @Pazi thank you for responding. I understand it is logical to do that. But could you add more explanation? Is there any standards like html from w3c?

Comment: Unfortunatel not, but this is a generally coding convetion, which every project clearly follows. Look at symfony itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By PMD you mean [PHP  Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/)?

If so, since you have a setup with Jenkins and PHP Mess Detector, I assume you actually care about code smells and readability.

With that in mind, my advice to you is: rename all of your boolean methods to follow the `isSomething()` or `hasSomething()` conventions.

Its important to notice though what code convention guide you follow.

That is very simple and quick to achieve, and will give you lots of benefits, such as:

- Possible bugs. Bugs are not always wrongly written code. A lot of times, poor conditions or bad management of scope can generate pretty hard to find bugs.
- Suboptimal code. Bad looking code can and most likely will be dificult to read. This is suboptimal code.
- Overcomplicated expressions
- Unused parameters, methods or properties

Comment: thank you for answering. Yes, I mean PHPMD. Since you mention lots of benefits, could you update the answer mentioning some of them? I am not aware of these yet.

Comment: Added a little more info. =D